# Downgrade Nodejs and Npm

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

Hello everyone how i can downgrade my version of **nodejs** and **npm** under **ubuntu** ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can downgrade **npm** by simple pasting a needed version:

For example:

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

Be sure that it's downgraded:

```
npm -v
```

2. To downgrade **nodejs**, you can also do so by simple pasting a needed version.

For example:

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.10.3
```

Be sure that it's downgraded:

```
$ node -v
v6.10.3
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i try this command : ```npm install -g npm@3.10.10``` my terminal say ```/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@3.10.10
added 266 packages from 544 contributors in 3.787s
``` and when i try ```npm -v``` i am in the same version. How i can switch (or use) the new added npm version please ? Thanks

Comment: Hello! Did you run this command using "sudo"? I believe admin privileges helps to solve this